# CALL_EXCEPTION when calling contract

Tags: solidity

I have a very big smart contract, and i deployed it to mainnet (ethereum mainnet). I encountered some problem with gas but i managed to solve them. I tried to execute one of the function in the contract but got this error:

> Error: transaction failed [ See:
> https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]

i clicked the link that brought me to the ethers.js documentation (Because I'm using ethersJS) and i checked everything that the documentation says about this error:

- The code exists on chain (ethereum mainnet) but **its not verified** (address: 0x7221a612Fc346fa218F9f64B4B4283782F639ea0)
- I'm accessing the right code
- The code doesn't reverts during a require statement
- I'm not using the wrong ABI

I'm very confused why the error is showing up and if somebody had any suggestion that would be very useful.

**Full Contract:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";


contract Arbitrage is DyDxFlashLoan {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uRouter;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sRouter;

    address public owner;

    constructor(address _uRouter, address _sRouter) {
        uRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uRouter);
        sRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sRouter);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint256 _flashAmount,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external {
        console.log("Balance before", IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this)));
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _flashAmount,
            balanceBefore
        );
        flashloan(_tokenA, _flashAmount, data);
    }

    function callFunction(
        address,
        Info calldata,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external onlyPool {
        (
            bool _startOnUniswap,
            address _tokenA,
            address _tokenB,
            uint256 flashAmount,
            uint256 balanceBefore
        ) = abi.decode(data, (bool, address, address, uint256, uint256));

        console.log("Balance after:", IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this)));
        uint balanceAfter = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));

        require(
            balanceAfter - balanceBefore == flashAmount,
            "Didn't receive flash loan"
        );

        address[] memory tokens = new address[](2);

        tokens[0] = _tokenA;
        tokens[1] = _tokenB;

        if (_startOnUniswap == true) {
            swapOnUniswap(flashAmount, 0, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnSushiswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                0,
                tokens
            );
        } else {
            // console.log("Ho 10 WETH e li swappo per x COMPOUND");
            console.log(
                "Balance of WETH before swap:",
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this))
            );
            swapOnSushiswap(flashAmount, 0, tokens);
            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            // console.log("Ho x COMPOUND e li swappo per >10 WETH");
            swapOnUniswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                0,
                tokens
            );
            console.log(
                "Balance of WETH after swap:",
                IERC20(tokens[1]).balanceOf(address(this))
            );
        }
    }

    function swapOnUniswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(uRouter), _amountIn),
            "Uniswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        console.log(
            "UNISWAP: Input tokens (COMP):",
            amounts[0],
            "Output tokens (ETH):",
            amounts[1]
        );
    }

    function swapOnSushiswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(sRouter), _amountIn),
            "Sushiswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = sRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        console.log(
            "SUSHISWAP: Input tokens (ETH):",
            amounts[0],
            "Output tokens (COMP):",
            amounts[1]
        );
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external {
        console.log("Owner balance:", IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(owner));
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only owner can withdraw");
        ERC20(_tokenAddress).transfer(
            owner,
            IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this))
        );
        console.log("Owner balance", IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(owner));
    }
}
```

**The code that executes the transaction:**

```
  const address = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, mainnetProvider);
  if (process.env.IS_DEPLOYED === true) {
    const options = {
      gasLimit: 2500000,
      maxFeePerGas: 40000000000,
    };
    const trade = await arbitrageContract
      .connect(address)
      .executeTrade(
        process.env.TOKEN_WETH_MAINNET,
        process.env.TOKEN_COMPOUND_MAINNET,
        ethers.BigNumber.from("10000000000000000000"),
        startOnUniswap,
        options
      );

    receipt = await trade.wait();
    console.log("sending eth to contract...");
    const withdraw = await arbitrageContract
      .connect(address)
      .withdraw(process.env.TOKEN_WETH_MAINNET);
    await withdraw.wait();
    console.log("sent eth to owner successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("CURRENTLY ON TEST MODE");
  }
```

**Txn Hash**

```
0x7c829bff4b541178bdb8cfae4adb6a53050c8ee4a23bffe57caabe69fd36d47d
```

**Input Data**

```
0x3ad83bfa000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2000000000000000000000000c00e94cb662c3520282e6f5717214004a7f268880000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008ac7230489e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Which function are you trying to execute?

Comment: the executeTrade function, in the Aribtrage contract

Comment: `function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint256 _flashAmount,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external {
        console.log("Balance before", IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this)));
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _flashAmount,
            balanceBefore
        );
        flashloan(_tokenA, _flashAmount, data);
    }`

Comment: Can you share the input data and tx hash?  It might be easiest to punch those into Tenderly transaction simulator to find the error.

Comment: thank you very much, i added them to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your called reverted is from a require statement that does not provide any message string.

```
require(balanceOf[src] >= wad);
```

This is where your call reverted. You can look it up with Tenderly.

This require statement is in the WETH9 contract.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error message in ethers.js doesn't show any useful information, so you can use the method below to find out a little more when you encounter an ethers.js error.

path: node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/providers/http.js Line:35

```
// AS-IS
function isErrorResponse(response) {
    return typeof response.error !== "undefined";
}

// TO-BE
function isErrorResponse(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return typeof response.error !== "undefined";
}
```

We could try to figure out what we can do based on that message.

Comment: thank you very much i will try it out

Comment: I tried this but the message error didn't change